# Rendering very large image from scratch then splitting it into tiles (for Google Maps)

Tags: image, google-maps, image-processing, google-maps-api-3, gdi+

I have a large set of google maps api v3 polylines and markers that need to be rendered as transparent PNG's (implemented as ImageMapType). I've done all the math/geometry regarding transformations from latLng to pixel and tile coordinates.

The problem is: at the maximum allowable zoom for my app, that is 18, the compound image would span at least 80000 pixels both in width and height. So rendering it in one piece, then splitting it into tiles becomes impossible.

I tried the method of splitting polylines beforehand and placing the parts into tiles, then rendering each tile alone, which up until now works almost fine. But it will become very difficult when I will need to draw stylized markers / text and other fancy stuff, etc.

So far I used C# GDI+ as the drawing methods (the ol' Bitmap / Graphics pair).

Many questions here are about splitting an already existing image, storing, and linking it to the API. I already know how to do that.

My problem is how do I draw the initial very large image then split it up? It doesn't really need to be a true image/bitmap/call it whatever you want solution. A friend suggested me to use SVG but I don't know any good rendering solutions to suit my needs.

To make it a little easier to comprehend, think it in terms of input/output. My input is the data that I need to draw (lines, circles, text, etc) that spreads across tens of thousands of pixels, and the output must be the tiles. I really don't care what the 'magic box' is, and I don't even care what the platform is.

Comment: This feels like reinventing the wheel... Doesn't Google Maps already do most of the work you are describing here?

Comment: My goal is to display a full feature map (with all sorts of symbols, arrows, descriptions, etc). And there are over 2000 polylines and markers. Loading them all on the client browser would be a disaster, and even if you optimize it, I don't want anyone to have access to the actual polyline data. I need something very visual and very fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem when creating custom tiles, and you are on the right track with your solution of creating one tile at a time. You just need to add some strategy to the process. What I do is like this:

```
Pseudo code:
for each tile {
  - determine the lat/lon corners of the tile.
  - query the database and load the objects that are within this tile.
  for each object{
    - calculate the tile pixels on which the object should be painted. [*A*]
    - draw the object on the tile.
    - Save the tile. (you're done with this tile).
  }
}
```

alternatively:

```
    Pseudo code:
    - for each object to be drawn {
      - determine what tile the object should be painted on.
      - calculate the tile pixels on which the object should be painted.[*A*]
      - get that tile, if it doesn't yet exist create a new one.
      - draw the object on the tile.
      - Save the tile. (you might need to draw more on this tile later)
}
```

I do this with Perl and the GD library.

`[*A*]` When painting objects that span more than one tile, if the object begins on the current tile then part of it will be left out automatically because you'll be attempting to paint outside the tile, while if the object began on the previous tile and you're drawing the second part then the pixel numbers should be negative, meaning that it began on the neighbor tile.

This is a bit hard to explain in a written post so please feel free to ask for further clarification if you need it and I'll edit the answer.

Comment: That's what I did, sort of. I managed to handle if a line for example spans more than 1 tile, and even managed to draw on non-adjacent tiles (if you have a very long line, there will be tiles with no vertices, but with the line passing through). The major problem arises when you use complicated styles (dashed lines, big stroke widths, etc) because they're very hard to control geometrically. Simplest example: if you have a line that runs on the edge of a tile, and part of it's stroke is in the adjacent tile, how do you DECIDE that part of it's stroke should be drawn on the adjacent tile?

Comment: I emphasized "DECIDE" because drawing would be essentially easy in GDI+, because, as you said, it doesn't matter if the coordinates are outside the tile, it will just render what's inside. The problem is how to effectively calculate which tiles to render for a particular object that extends by it's style, and not by it's coordinates.

Comment: It is not a problem. it is actually explained, (briefly), in my reply under note [A]. I'll try to add an image to make it more clear, but I only have use of 1 hand to operate the computer so, it will take me a while. I might be able to add the image later today or tomorrow. :-)

Comment: A fast way to find the boundaries of tiles is this page here - especially if you only need some tiles: http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend getting to know GDAL (http://gdal.org) and it's libraries. It has libraries for rasterization, tiling, data conversion, projections, warping, and much more.

Comment: On a quick look, this seems like a very very promising solution. I'll check it out and come back with feedback. Thank you very much

Comment: Also, I wouldn't mind if you have some examples regarding my question, because I got absolutely lost when I started browsing the GDAL site

Comment: I don't have anything spot on, but I do have something similar here: https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/raster That's for KML for Google Earth but it addresses many of the methods you'll need